# How to bind to the Tag property of another element

Tags: wpf, data-binding

What I want is to binding the Image source to the **ImageData** property of **MyViewModel** instance. For some reason, I cannot set MyWindow.DataContext as MyViewModel instance (it is leagacy code and it will cost too much to do this).

The code snippet is as below and there will be the following error

> System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'ElementName=myButton'. BindingExpression:Path=Tag; DataItem=null; target element is 'Image' (Name=''); target property is 'Source' (type 'ImageSource')

```
// This is the view model class
class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   public string Name {get ... ;set ... ; }

   public string ImageData { ... }
}

// this is the window class
class MyWindow
{
   private MyViewModel _ViewModel = new MyViewModel();
   public MyViewModel ViewModel 
   { get { return _ViewModel; } }
   . . .
}

MyWindow.Xaml

<devComponent:ButtonDropDown x:Name="myButton" 
        Tooltip="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type mf:MyWindow}}, Path=ViewModel.Name}"
        Tag="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type mf:MyWindow}}, Path=ViewModel.ImageData}"
        ...>
  <devComponent:ButtonDropDown.Image>
    <Image Source="{Binding Path=Tag, ElementName=myButton}" />
  </devComponent:ButtonDropDown.Image>

</devComponent:ButtonDropDown>
```

I also tried to use below code but it still does not work because Image does not belong to the visual tree

> Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='xxxxx', AncestorLevel='1''

```
  <Button.Image>
    <Image Source="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type mf:MyWindow}}, Path=MyViewModel.ImageData}" />
  </Button.Image>
```

Comment: `Button.Image` is supposed to be `Button.Content`? The WPF Button class has no Image property. Besides that you could easily set the Window's DataContext by `DataContext="{Binding ViewModel, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"`. At least, `MyViewModel.ImageData` is an invalid property path, because `MyViewModel` is the type, not the the name of the view model property.

Comment: Finally, returning `new MyViewModel()` from the ViewModel property will create a new view model instance for each binding to that property. Use a single instance instead. You could simply drop the ViewModel property entirely, and add `DataContext = new MyViewModel()` to the Window's constructor.

Comment: @Clemens thanks for pointing out the mistakes, I have updated my question. The reason I do not want to set DataContext for MyWindow is because what I handled is legacy code and there will be other issues if I set DataContext. The button is actually a 3rd party ButtonDropDown button from DevComponent.

Comment: How about having that image as a resource?

Comment: @Karolis The image source will change based on some business logic

Comment: @Carlos Liu Assuming you know what the images are ahead of time can't you have a folder of possible images and then select one from there based on your business logic?

Comment: Dynamic resource :) that is only suggestion I can provide given information in question.

Comment: @Karolis actually the image is selected by the user from his local disk and saved in database, then the UI will read from database and show it on the view

Comment: I have tested it with Button, not with devComponent:ButtonDropDown and it works for me(Tag bound with relative source, Image.Source bound with ElmentName ).

Comment: @Rekshino thanks, I will try to contact DevComponent support